# PublishAoT warnings: is there any way to get the callgraph?

Tags: c#, .net-core

Using dotnet core 8. Relevant build options:

```
<PublishTrimmed>true</PublishTrimmed>
<TrimmerSingleWarn>false</TrimmerSingleWarn>
<ILLinkTreatWarningsAsErrors>false</ILLinkTreatWarningsAsErrors>
<PublishAoT>true</PublishAoT>
```

Suppose this produces a warning e.g.

```
/_/src/libraries/System.Linq.Expressions/src/System/Linq/Expressions/Compiler/DelegateHelpers.Generated.cs(114): AOT analysis warning IL3050: System.Linq.Expressions.Compiler.DelegateHelpers.TryMakeVBStyledCallSite(Type[]): Using member 'System.Type.MakeGenericType(Type[])' which has 'RequiresDynamicCodeAttribute' can break functionality when AOT compiling. The native code for this instantiation might not be available at runtime.
```

Now, I'm not directly referencing DelegateHelpers in my code; *something* is, in one of my dependencies. The AOT analysis must have kept track of the callgraph from Main() to this problematic call site as part of trimming. Is there any way to get more detail about how it's reached this conclusion? Or otherwise find out which dependency I'm using references the problematic code?

I have marked all my code with `<IsAotCompatible>true</IsAotCompatible>` and dealt with the warnings that produces. This warning is not produced from regular trim analysis; it *only* appears once PublishAoT is enabled.